# How can you decimate data depending on zoom level of plot?

Tags: python, bigdata, holoviews, datashader

The documentation for holoviews' [decimate operation](https://holoviews.org/reference_manual/holoviews.operation.html?highlight=decimate#holoviews.operation.decimate) seems to imply that if max_samples=100, say, you get a plot with 100 points at most no matter the zoom level.

With the following example, I see no new dots appear as I zoom in... can holoviews achieve this? can some other package?

```
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# from holoviews import opts
# from holoviews.operation.datashader import datashade, shade, dynspread, spread
# from holoviews.operation.datashader import rasterize, ResamplingOperation
from holoviews.operation import decimate

hv.extension('bokeh', width=200)

# Default values suitable for this notebook
decimate.max_samples=100

np.random.seed(1)
points = hv.Points(np.random.multivariate_normal((0,0), [[0.1, 0.1], [0.1, 1.0]], (1_000_000,)))

decimate(points)
```

The above code seems to decimate data once, and then show the same dots regardless of x_range and y_range...

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: The decimate operation should give you a different 100 samples each time you zoom, which I've verified for your code above using HoloViews 1.15.0. The dots do stop changing if you zoom in enough that the data only has less than 100 samples in the current viewport, but it updates regularly up until then. If you aren't seeing updates, can you list your HoloViews and Bokeh and Jupyter versions and maybe record a little video of what happens, including what's on the JS console (under Developer Tools in Chrome)?

Comment: holoviews 1.15.0
bokeh 2.4.3

Was running inside VS Code 1.71.2 and that didn't work. Your question made me try jupyterlab (3.4.7) and it worked like a charm! 

I wasn't sure if I was misunderstanding docs or misusing code. Looks like neither. Thanks for your help and let me know if you need more info from me.

Comment: Sounds good! It might work in VSCode too if you `import panel as pn`, `pn.extension(comms='vscode')`, then `pn.pane(decimate(points))`, but I'm not a VSCode user and haven't tested that.